# Click on a row to open a modal with the row's data

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, react-table

I am using react-table and here's my table:

```
<ReactTable
          data={this.props.data}
          columns={[
            {
              Header: "id",
              accessor: "id",
              width: 50
            },
            {
              Header: "Name",
              accessor: "name",
              width: 200
            },
            {
              Header: "",
              id: "id",
              Cell: ({ row }) => (
                <button onClick={e => this.handleButtonClick(e, row)}>
                  Click Me
                </button>
              )
            }
          ]}
          defaultPageSize={10}
          showPaginationBottom
       />
```

the action after the button click

```
handleButtonClick = (e, row) => {
    this.setState({ visible: true});
    return 
       <Modal 
          title="title" 
          visible={this.state.visible}
        >
        // show data here
    </Modal>
  };
```

So this is how I am working right now, but the modal isn't getting displayed. Can anyone help me with this? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why you return the modal with `handleButtonClick` function instead of add it with `ReactTable`

```
<ReactTable
          data={this.props.data}
          columns={[
            {
              Header: "id",
              accessor: "id",
              width: 50
            },
            {
              Header: "Name",
              accessor: "name",
              width: 200
            },
            {
              Header: "",
              id: "id",
              Cell: ({ row }) => (
                <button onClick={e => this.handleButtonClick(e, row)}>
                  Click Me
                </button>
              )
            }
          ]}
          defaultPageSize={10}
          showPaginationBottom
       />

      {this.state.visible && <Modal 
          title="title" 
          visible={this.state.visible}
        >
        // show data here
    </Modal>}

handleButtonClick = (e, row) => {
    this.setState({ visible: true});
  };
```