# React open pop up from react-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, popup, bootstrap-modal, react-table

I am building an app with react.js, it has a table built using the [react table library](https://react-table.tanstack.com/).

Within this table I would like to have a button (or whatever) that will open a pop up showing a png. The png is determined by the cell content so may or may not be the same in all pop ups.

It appears I need to use a very simple modal so I decided to build it using the [react bootstrap library](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/modal/) as follows

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

const PopUp = ({ link }) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow} size="sm">
        Pathway
      </Button>

      <Modal
        show={show}
        onHide={handleClose}
        dialogClassName={'IMG_path'}
        size="lg"
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>IMG title</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body closeButton>
          <img src={"./img/" + link}
               id="id"
               alt="description"
               className="img-fluid"/>
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};

export default PopUp;
```

Then I tested it next to the react table, I mean within the same div, and it worked perfectly fine.

Then I added to the table using the following code

```
import React from "react";
import { useTable, usePagination, useSortBy } from 'react-table';

import PopUp from "./PopUp";

const MakePopup = ({ values }) =>  values && <PopUp link={values} /> ;

function Table({ columns, data }) {
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    prepareRow,
    page, 
    canPreviousPage,
    canNextPage,
    pageOptions,
    pageCount,
    gotoPage,
    nextPage,
    previousPage,
    setPageSize,
    state: { pageIndex, pageSize },
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
      autoResetPage: true,
      initialState: { pageIndex: 0 },
    },
    // hook for sorting
    useSortBy,
    // hook for pagination
    usePagination
  )

  return (
    <>
      <table {...getTableProps()} className={"table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"}>
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                // Add the sorting props to control sorting. For this example
                // we can add them into the header props
                <th {...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())} scope={"col"}>
                  {column.render('Header')}
                  <span>
                    {column.isSorted
                      ? column.isSortedDesc
                        ? ' '
                        : ' '
                      : ''}
                  </span>
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {page.map((row, i) => {
            prepareRow(row)
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map(cell => {
                  return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                })}
              </tr>
            )
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      {/*
        Pagination can be built however you'd like.
        This is just a very basic UI implementation:
      */}
      <div className="pagination">
        <select
          value={pageSize}
          onChange={e => {
            setPageSize(Number(e.target.value))
          }}
        >
          {[10, 20, 30, 40, 50].map(pageSize => (
            <option key={pageSize} value={pageSize}>
              Show {pageSize}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>{' '}
        <button onClick={() => gotoPage(0)} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
          {'<<'}
        </button>{' '}
        <button onClick={() => previousPage()} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
          {'<'}
        </button>{' '}
        <span className='page-of'>
          Page{' '}
          <strong>
            {pageIndex + 1} of {pageOptions.length}
          </strong>{' '}
        </span>
        <button onClick={() => nextPage()} disabled={!canNextPage}>
          {'>'}
        </button>{' '}
        <button onClick={() => gotoPage(pageCount - 1)} disabled={!canNextPage}>
          {'>>'}
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

function MyTable(props) {
  const columns = [
    {
      Header: 'AA',
      accessor: 'AA',
    },
    {
      Header: 'BB',
      accessor: 'BB',
      sortType: "basic"
    },
    ...
    ...
    ...
    {
      Header: 'Img',
      accessor: 'url',
      sortType: "basic",
      disableSortBy: true,
      Cell: ({ cell: {value} }) => <MakePopup values={value} />
    }
  ];

  const data = props.tableData;

  return (
      <Table columns={columns} data={data} />
  )
}
```

Now the cells have the button to call the modal but it never appears :(

Searching here I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50500206/7902133) and [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63551465/7902133) answer indicating that the modal should be outside the table instead of next the button within each cell so I modified the code to this

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useTable, usePagination, useSortBy } from 'react-table';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

// PopUp 
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
const [link, setLink] = useState('.png');

const handleClick = ( link ) => {
  setShow(true);
  setLink(link);
};

function Table({ columns, data }) {

  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    prepareRow,
    page, 
    canPreviousPage,
    canNextPage,
    pageOptions,
    pageCount,
    gotoPage,
    nextPage,
    previousPage,
    setPageSize,
    state: { pageIndex, pageSize },
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
      autoResetPage: true,
      initialState: { pageIndex: 0 },
    },
    // hook for sorting
    useSortBy,
    // hook for pagination
    usePagination
  )

  return (
    <>
      <table {...getTableProps()} className={"table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"}>
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                // Add the sorting props to control sorting. For this example
                // we can add them into the header props
                <th {...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())} scope={"col"}>
                  {column.render('Header')}
                  {/* Add a sort direction indicator */}
                  <span>
                    {column.isSorted
                      ? column.isSortedDesc
                        ? ' '
                        : ' '
                      : ''}
                  </span>
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {page.map((row, i) => {
            prepareRow(row)
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map(cell => {
                  return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                })}
              </tr>
            )
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      {/*
        Pagination can be built however you'd like.
        This is just a very basic UI implementation:
      */}
      <div className="pagination">
        <select
          value={pageSize}
          onChange={e => {
            setPageSize(Number(e.target.value))
          }}
        >
          {[10, 20, 30, 40, 50].map(pageSize => (
            <option key={pageSize} value={pageSize}>
              Show {pageSize}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>{' '}
        <button onClick={() => gotoPage(0)} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
          {'<<'}
        </button>{' '}
        <button onClick={() => previousPage()} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
          {'<'}
        </button>{' '}
        <span className='page-of'>
          Page{' '}
          <strong>
            {pageIndex + 1} of {pageOptions.length}
          </strong>{' '}
        </span>
        <button onClick={() => nextPage()} disabled={!canNextPage}>
          {'>'}
        </button>{' '}
        <button onClick={() => gotoPage(pageCount - 1)} disabled={!canNextPage}>
          {'>>'}
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

function MyTable(props) {
  const columns = [
    {
      Header: 'AA',
      accessor: 'AA',
    },
    {
      Header: 'BB',
      accessor: 'BB',
      sortType: "basic"
    },
    ...
    ...
    ...
    {
      Header: 'Img',
      accessor: 'url',
      sortType: "basic",
      disableSortBy: true,
      Cell: ({ cell: { png } }) => png && (
        <Button
          variant="primary"
          onClick={ () => handleClick(png) }
          size="sm"
        >
          Pathway
        </Button>
      )
    }
  ];

  const data = props.genesData;

  return (
    <>
      <Table columns={columns} data={data} />
      <Modal
        show={show}
        onHide={handleClose}
        dialogClassName={'IMG_path'}
        size="lg"
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>IMG title</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body closeButton>
          <img src={"./img/" + link}
               id="id"
               alt="description"
               className="img-fluid"/>
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    </>
  )
}

export default MyTable;
```

Now I get the following compilation error and the app does not start

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See react-invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and
>    fix this problem.

which points to this part of the code

```
   4 | import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
   5 | 
   6 | // PopUp states
>  7 | const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
   8 | const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
   9 | // const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
  10 | const [link, setLink] = useState('.png');
```

Now I am unsure of how to address this. I have been considering using a state management library such as redux but I think it will not solve the problem. I am using modals from bootstrap but I would use what-ever-it-is since I think the modals may be a little bit to much for the functionality I need.

Thanks

=========================

Edit based on answer

As recommended by @Afzal Zubair I moved the hooks inside the function as follows :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useTable, usePagination, useSortBy } from 'react-table';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

function Table({ columns, data }) {

  // PopUp states
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  // const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
  const [link, setLink] = useState('.png');

  const handleClick = ( link ) => {
    setShow(true);
    setLink(link);
  };

  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
  ...
  ...
  ...
  ...
  return (
    <>
      <Table columns={columns} data={data} />
      <Modal
        show={show}
        onHide={handleClose}
        dialogClassName={'IMG_path'}
        size="lg"
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>KEGG pathway</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body closeButton>
          <img src={"./img/" + link}
               alt="plant-pathogen_interaction"
               className="img-fluid"/>
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    </>
  )
}
```

Now I get a different compilation error

Failed to compile.

> ./src/components/table/ReactTable_PopUp.jsx   Line 193:27:
> 'handleClick' is not defined  no-undef   Line 208:15:  'show' is not
> defined         no-undef   Line 209:17:  'handleClose' is not defined
> no-undef   Line 217:32:  'link' is not defined         no-undef
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

referring to the following code

```
 190     Cell: ({ cell: { png } }) => png && (
 191       <Button
 192         variant="primary"
 193         onClick={ () => handleClick(png) }
 194         size="sm"
 195       >
 196         Pathway
 197       </Button>
 198     )
```

and

```
 204  return (
 205    <>
 206      <Table columns={columns} data={data} />
 207      <Modal
 208        show={show}
 209        onHide={handleClose}
```

and

```
 216        <Modal.Body closeButton>
 217          <img src={"./img/" + link}
 218               alt="plant-pathogen_interaction"
 219               className="img-fluid"/>
 220        </Modal.Body>
```

Thanks

====================================================================

SOLVED

@Afzal Zubair is right, the hooks needed to be moved to the Functional element, function `MyTable` in my code

```
function MyTable(props) {

  // PopUp states
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const [link, setLink] = useState('.png');

  const handleClick = ( link ) => {
    setShow(true);
    setLink(link);
  };  

  const columns = [
    {
      Header: 'AA',
      accessor: 'AA',
    },
    {
      Header: 'BB',
      accessor: 'BB',
      sortType: "basic"
    },
    ...
    ...
```

Now it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are using useState hooks outside react component.

```
   4 | import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
   5 | 
   6 | // PopUp states
>  7 | const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
   8 | const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
   9 | // const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
  10 | const [link, setLink] = useState('.png');
```

You should use the modal outside the Table components, but you cannot use react hooks outside the react components.

I suggest using these hooks inside the react component, Functional component to be precise.
You can refer to this document for better understanding, [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

Comment: You were right! I cannot believe I made this mistake. I moved the states to the function and  updated the question with the new error

Comment: @Alfonso I'm glad that my answer was helpful. :)